# How to ensure the sshuttle is working?

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunnel

I just started experimenting with [SSHuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) as a VPN for insecure networks.  It starts up and seems to run just fine, but what I hit http://www.whatismyip.org/ my IP remains the same as when I'm not running sshuttle.

Shouldn't my public IP change to the outside world?  How can I verify that my traffic is being tunneled?

I'm running an OSX Lion client connecting to a Linux SSH server.

```
sshuttle -r MYSERVER -vvv --dns 0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to go to a website like this:

http://www.whatismyip.com/

Load this website both pre-sshuttle and post-sshuttle and compare the two.  See if it changes, if it does, then that means everything is working.

Edit: Wow,I can't believe I completely missed the second line...?

In that case, it's probably not working, are you running the command as root?  Also, try it without "--dns".

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is likely returning a cached version of the page, a hard refresh would probably show you your tunnel IP.